# Single Static Block Linking To 50 Different URLs

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block

I have a banner image that I need to display in approximately 70 categories on my website.

The banner will link from one specific category to another specific category, but will be different every time.

Example:
Banner in category 1, will link to category 1a.
Banner in category 2, will link to category 2a.
Banner in category 3, will link to category 3a.
And so on...

Is there a way to control the link URL of the banner in a way that means I only have to create a single static block to handle this, such as code that checks which category the banner is being displayed in, and having that determine the link URL applied to the banner.

This would mean I can use a single static block...

Or am I stuck with creating 70 static blocks because I need each banner to link to 70 different categories?